# Perl: Trying to speed up parsing a delimited file

Tags: regex, perl, split

I have a large flat text file with lines that hold name/value pairs ("varname=value"). These pairs are seperated by a multi-character delimiter. So a single line in this file might look like this:

```
var1=value1|^|var2=value2|^|var3=value3|^|var4=value4
```

Each line holds about 50 name/value pairs.

I need to iterate through the lines of this file (there are about 100,000 lines) and store the name/value pairs in a hash so that

```perl
$field{'var1'} = value1
$field{'var2'} = value2
etc...
```

What I did was this:

```perl
# $line holds a single line from the file

my @fields = split( /\Q|^|\E/, $line );
foreach my $field (@fields) {
  my ($name, $value) = split( /=/, $field );
  $hash{$name} = $value;
}
```

Doing this for each line of the entire file takes (on my PC) about 2 seconds. This doesn't seem like a long time, but I really want to speed this up by quite a bit.

Of this 2 seconds, the first split takes about 0.6 seconds, while the foreach loop takes about 1.4 seconds. So I thought I'd get rid of the foreach loop and put it all in a single split:

```perl
%hash = split( /\Q|^|\E|=/, $line );
```

Much to my surprise, parsing the entire file this way took a full second longer! My question isn't really why this takes longer (although it would be a nice bonus to understand why), but my question is if there are any other (faster) ways to get the job done.

Thanks in advance.

**------ Edit below this line ------**

I just found out that changing this:

```perl
%hash = split( /\Q|^|\E|=/, $line );
```

into this:

```perl
$line =~ s/\Q|^|\E/=/g;
%hash = split( /=/, $line );
```

makes it three times faster! Parsing the entire file this way now takes just over a second...

**------ Snippet below this line ------**

```perl
use strict;
use Time::HiRes qw( time );

my $line = "a=1|^|b=2|^|c=3|^|d=4|^|e=5|^|f=6|^|g=7|^|h=8|^|i=9|^|j=10|^|k=11|^|l=12|^|m=13|^|n=14|^|o=15|^|p=16|^|q=17|^|r=18|^|s=19|^|t=20|^|u=21|^|v=22|^|w=23|^|x=24|^|y=25|^|z=26|^|aa=27|^|ab=28|^|ac=29|^|ad=30|^|ae=31|^|af=32|^|ag=33|^|ah=34|^|ai=35|^|aj=36|^|ak=37|^|al=38|^|am=39|^|an=40|^|ao=41|^|ap=42|^|aq=43|^|ar=44|^|as=45|^|at=46|^|au=47|^|av=48|^|aw=49|^|ax=50";

ResetTimer();
my %hash;
for( my $i = 1; $i <= 100000; $i++ ) {
  my @fields = split( /\Q|^|\E/, $line );
  foreach my $field (@fields) {
    my ($name, $value) = split( /=/, $field );
    $hash{$name} = $value;
  }
}
print Elapsed() . "\n";

ResetTimer();
%hash = ();
for( my $i = 1; $i <= 100000; $i++ ) {
  %hash = split( /\Q|^|\E|=/, $line );
}
print Elapsed() . "\n";

ResetTimer();
%hash = ();
for( my $i = 1; $i<=100000; $i++ ) {
  $line =~ s/\Q|^|\E/=/g;
  %hash = split( /=/, $line );
}
print Elapsed() . "\n";

################################################################################################################################
BEGIN {
  my $startTime;
  sub ResetTimer {
    $startTime = time();
    return $startTime;
  }
  sub Elapsed {
    return time() - $startTime;
  }
}
```

Comment: A bit more sample data might be helpful. OR a runnable snippet.

Comment: I've added a runnable snippet above. :)

Comment: Contributed an example with some comparative tests. (e.g. using `Benchmark`)

Comment: If you really need the extra speed, you may want to consider writing [primitive purpose built split in XS](https://www.nu42.com/2013/02/splitting-long-lines-is-slow.html).

Answer (score 6):

I can't easily answer your performance question, because I'd need a test case. But I'd *guess* that it's to do with how the regular expression is being processed.

You can see what that's doing with `use re 'debug';`, and that'll print the regular expression steps.

But for the broader question - I'd probably just tackle it with a global (assuming your data is as simple as the example):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings; 
use Data::Dumper;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
   my %row = m/(\w+)=(\w+)/g;
   print Dumper \%row;
}

__DATA__
var1=value1|^|var2=value2|^|var3=value3|^|var4=value4
```

You can use lookahead/behind to match delimiters if you've got more complicated things in there, but because it's one regex per line, you're invoking the regex engine less often, and that'll *probably* be faster. (But I can't tell you for sure without a test case).

If your data *is* more complicated, then perhaps:

```
my %row = s/\Q|^|\E/\n/rg =~ m/(.*)=(.*)/g;
```

This will 'force' splitting the input into a new line, and then match 'anything' = 'anything'. But that's probably overkill unless your values include whitespace/pipes/metachars.

With editing your test case to use `Benchmark`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw ( cmpthese );

my $line =
  "a=1|^|b=2|^|c=3|^|d=4|^|e=5|^|f=6|^|g=7|^|h=8|^|i=9|^|j=10|^|k=11|^|l=12|^|m=13|^|n=14|^|o=15|^|p=16|^|q=17|^|r=18|^|s=19|^|t=20|^|u=21|^|v=22|^|w=23|^|x=24|^|y=25|^|z=26|^|aa=27|^|ab=28|^|ac=29|^|ad=30|^|ae=31|^|af=32|^|ag=33|^|ah=34|^|ai=35|^|aj=36|^|ak=37|^|al=38|^|am=39|^|an=40|^|ao=41|^|ap=42|^|aq=43|^|ar=44|^|as=45|^|at=46|^|au=47|^|av=48|^|aw=49|^|ax=50";

sub double_split {
   my %hash;
   my @fields = split( /\Q|^|\E/, $line );
   foreach my $field (@fields) {
      my ( $name, $value ) = split( /=/, $field );
      $hash{$name} = $value;
   }
}

sub single_split {
   my %hash = split( /\Q|^|\E|=/, $line );
}

sub re_replace_then_split {
   $line =~ s/\Q|^|\E/=/g;
   my %hash = split( /=/, $line );
}

sub single_regex {
   my %hash = $line =~ m/(\w+)=(\w+)/g;
}

sub compound {
   my %hash = $line =~ s/\Q|^|\E/\n/rg =~ m/(.*)=(.*)/g;
}

cmpthese(
   1_000_000,
   {  "Double Split"                 => \&double_split,
      "single split with regex"      => \&single_split,
      "Replace then split"           => \&re_replace_then_split,
      "Single Regex"                 => \&single_regex,
      "regex to linefeed them match" => \&compound
   }
);
```

Looks like the results come out like:

```
                                 Rate Double Split single split with regex Single Regex Replace then split regex to linefeed them match
Double Split                  18325/s           --                     -4%         -34%               -56%                         -97%
single split with regex       19050/s           4%                      --         -31%               -54%                         -97%
Single Regex                  27607/s          51%                     45%           --               -34%                         -96%
Replace then split            41733/s         128%                    119%          51%                 --                         -93%
regex to linefeed them match 641026/s        3398%                   3265%        2222%              1436%                           --
```

... I'm a bit suspicious of that last, because that's absurdly faster. There's probably caching of results happening there.

But looking at it, what's slowing you down is the alternation in the regex:

```
sub single_split_with_alt {
   my %hash = split( /\Q|^|\E|=/, $line );
}

sub single_split {
      my %hash = split( /[\|\^\=]+/, $line );
}
```

(I know that latter *might* not be quite what you want, but it's for illustrative purposes)

Gives:

```
                Rate  alternation single split
alternation  19135/s           --         -37%
single split 30239/s          58%           --
```

But there does come a point where this is moot, because your limiting factor is disk IO, not CPU.

Comment: "*because your limiting factor is disk IO, not CPU.*" Probably not. On my really old system with a slow SSD, it takes 0.7 seconds to read an chomp every line of a 100,000 line file with 50 such fields on each line.

Comment: compound() is actually the slowest of the bunch but comes out fastest in your example because it's run against an already altered $line (it's changed in re_replace_then_split() ).

Comment: Well spotted. I figured there was a reason that was so fast, but hadn't dug deeper. (Rerunning my test without including the replace-then-split gives more sensible numbers)